# Trouble with scientific notation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, formatting

I am having trouble getting my stuff to go in scientific notation. I have read the help page on in and I am doing what is suggested but it's not working. For example, I have...

```
Np1 = 100;
pTab3 = Table[{(qpt + Np1 - 1)!/(qpt!*((Np1 - 1)!))}, {qpt, 0, 80}] // ScientificForm
```

When I shift enter this I get numbers like 7217476909573650726969167092426513519286500 and similar, large numbers (I didn't put the output of the code in here because it's super long). I have tried doing things like putting 'ScientificForm[%]' before the 'pTab3' line, and putting the pTab3 line in brackets and stuff but it still will not show me my values in scientific notation. How do I do this??? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try using `N[]` first: `ScientificForm[N[12340000000]]`

Comment: You do not want to include `ScientificForm` in the definition of `pTab3`. Use parentheses to isolate the definition from the formatting. `(pTab3 = ...) // 
  N // ScientificForm` or `(pTab3 = ... // N) // ScientificForm`